# Coyote time for 2D platformer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a novice game designer and a coder new to the term 'coyote time.'
I've always felt its existence before or after practicing game design as a career ever so naturally playing other games, but now that I have to implement it to my own game I'm kind of confused how to actually attempt to do it.

My game is set up with modified CharacterController in 3D world space as an orthographic 2D platformer. If anyone could give me where to look for head start trying to implement this feature for the first time or a very simple example I'd appreciate it very very much. Google didn't quite cut it this time for me :(.

Comment: For reference, "coyote time" is the notion that, in a platformer game, if you jump a little bit too late, the jump still works. This is particularly evident in endless runner type games. Canabalt achieves this by having the player's hitbox actually 8 to 10 pixels *behind* the visible sprite.

Answer (score -1):

It's 11 months late but hey, maybe someone else will benefit from the answer.

Have a player variable called `coyoteTime`. Whenever the player touches the ground, set `coyoteTime` to a certain number between `0` and half a second. At every game update, reduce that number. If the player touches the ground, set it back to that number.

When the player tries to jump, `if (0 < coyoteTime)`, the player can jump.

This is basically just extra time to jump